# Using the following key, symbolize the following

Tags: logic

Using the following
key, symbolize the following

a = André

C
_ = _ is a cook

P _ = _ is a philosopher

W _ = _ is wise

> (a) If all philosophers
>   are cooks, then all cooks are philosophers.
>
> ∀x(Px↔Cx)→∀x(Cx∧Px)
>
> (b) If only philosophers are cooks, then all cooks are philosophers.
>
> ∀x(Px→Cx)→∀x(Cx→Px)
>
> (d) If only philosophers are wise, and John is a phil
>   osopher then he is wise.
>
> ∀x(Px→Wx)→(Pa→Wa)

is it correct? If it is wrong, please explain. ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not correct.

- Seperate the question.

All philosophers are cooks: That is all $x$ who is a philosopher is also a cook. $\forall x (Px \implies Cx)$

All cooks are philosophers: That is all $x$ who is a cook is also a philosopher.$\forall x (Cx \implies Px)$

If all philosophers cooks, then all cooks are philosophers: $(\forall x (Px \implies Cx)) \implies (\forall y (Py \implies Cy))$

- Again seperate:

Only philosophers are cooks. That is, if there is noone who is cook but not philosopher. $\neg\exists x(Cx \land \neg Px)$

We made the second part in the previous question. Then the answer is:

$(\neg\exists x(Cx \land \neg Px)) \implies (\forall y (Py \implies Cy))$

- All philosophers are wise: $\forall x (Px \implies Wx)$

Andre (I suppose it's not John but Andre) is a philosopher: $Pa$

He (Andre) is wise: $Wa$

Then the answer is: $((\forall x (Px \implies Wx)) \land Pa )\implies Wa$

Comment: its late but ty!

Answer (score 1):

They are all wrong, despite the exercises here being very elementary. It looks as if you should carefully read a good textbook presentation or two on how to translate into the language of predicate logic. Try, for example, Paul Teller's lucid *A Modern Formal Logic Primer*, now freely available from the author's website.

On (a), 'All philosophers are cooks' does not get translated with a biconditional, and 'all cooks are philosophers' does not get translated with a conjunction. Why use different connectives?

On (b) 'only philosophers are cooks' doesn't mean that all philosophers are cooks, which is what $\forall x (Px \to Cx)$ says. The same mistake is made in (d).

Comment: can you give me some example or answer for (a)?

Comment: (i) Translate  'All philosophers are cooks'. (ii) Translate 'all cooks are philosophers'. (iii) write down a conditional with the first as antecedent and the second as consequent. If you can't even do (i) and (ii) you shouldn't be asking questions here but reading a good textbook or two, as these are utterly basic.

Comment: I don't have the text book, but I have the notes which I don't understand at all. i) ∀x(Px→Cx)?  ii) ∀x(Cx→Px)

Comment: Then try reading Paul Teller's explanations of quantifiers in his A Modern Formal Logic Primer, as I say freely available from his website. But you'll find a couple of dozen good alternatives in your library: that's what the books are there for!

Comment: is it this one? http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu/pdf/. Also, in my notes..   All but only philosophers are cooks. = ∀x(Px↔Cx). why is this correct?